# General solution to Laplacian eigenvalue equation in hyperbolic space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

In hyperbolic space $H^n$ with metric $g=dr^2+\sinh^2 r\:g_{S^{n-1}}$, consider the Laplacian eigenvalue equation

$-\Delta u=c^2 u$.

I am concerned with the radial solution to the above equation, $u=u(r)$. So the equation becomes

$$v_{rr}+(n-1)\coth r\cdot u_r+c^2u=0.$$

What is the general solution to the equation above?

If we set $u(r)=\varphi(s)=\varphi(\frac{1-\cosh r}{2})$, we can get

$$ s(1-s)\varphi_{ss}+(\frac{n}{2}-ns)\varphi_s-c^2\varphi=0.$$

It is known that the solution is given by hypergeomertic functions. What is the general solution which is regular at the origin? Are there two independent solutions? Is the case $n=2$ simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be addressed [in:](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4406)

*Cohl, H.S.; Kalnins, E.G.*, [**Fourier and Gegenbauer expansions for a fundamental solution of the Laplacian in the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/45/14/145206), J. Phys. A, Math. Theor. 45, No. 14, Article ID 145206, 32 p. (2012). [ZBL1238.31006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1238.31006).

Comment: I had a quick view of this paper. Although it is about the question on sphere, it would be helpful for the question on hyperbolic space. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChangweiXiong oops, wrong reference, but right link (click on the "in:)

Comment: @ChangweiXiong fixed now.

Comment: Nice reference! I shall read it first.